# Mysql - Modify column data type on large table

Tags: mysql

I have a reasonably large InnoDB table (~100gb) in a MySQL 5.7 database. It is backed by a network-attached storage volume, which is a little slow but no problem for my use case.

One of the columns is currently a LONGTEXT but it actually contains serialized objects from memory. LONGTEXT clearly isn't the correct data type - it really should be a LONGBLOB and we're starting to see some code problems because of this.

In a test run of a plain ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ... LONGBLOB, it looked like it was doing a full table copy and rebuild, which was confirmed by the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations-table. This would cause too much downtime for me. I tried using both ALGORITHM=INPLACE and LOCK=NONE, but I got errors with both of these. The column which needs modifying is only about 20gb of the 100gb table.

Is there any way to do ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ... LONGBLOB on this column without causing significant downtime (>10 minutes for argument's sake)?

Comment: define "significant downtime" and "too much downtime"

Comment: If you need to rebuild the table then you're stuck rebuilding it unless you can rebuild to a new table, port over any changes made while you were porting it, port over any changes from that shorter period of time, then lock it and flip it.

Comment: @MaxMuster to put a number on it for argument's sake, let's say > 10 minutes is significant downtime